# alert from input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I have this script

```
<form id="logform">
    <input class="login" name="login" type="text"><br />
    <input class="password" name="password" type="password"><br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="login">
</form>

var username = $(".login").val();
var password = $(".password").val();
$(".submit").click(function() {
    alert(username);
});
```

and when I type text in input and click submit alert is empty ?

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/7mbqd2qg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below script with user name within click function

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
var username = $(".login").val();
alert(username);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify your code to assign value after submit:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    var username = $(".login").val();
    var password = $(".password").val();
    alert(username);
});
```

Because, value are being assigned when page is called. That is why username is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the user name before the `click` event is fired on document `load`, put in click event to get the value of username when `click` is triggered.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WF6g6/)**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
        var username = $(".login").val();
    var password = $(".password").val();
         alert(username);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the username/password *inside* the `submit` callback. The way you're code is written now, you're getting the username/password immediately, when they're still blank, and never getting the again.

Answer (score 0):

**the value of username get initialized on load so it will be always empty**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
alert($(".login").val()); //get the current value
});
```

or

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    var username = $(".login").val();
    alert(username);
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv94t/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the value before the submit click thats the issue

put the following codes inside the click function and try 
    var username = $(".login").val();
        var password = $(".password").val();

```
<form id="logform">
    <input class="login" name="login" type="text"><br />
    <input class="password" name="password" type="password"><br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="login">
    </form>

$(".submit").click(function(){
var username = $(".login").val();
var password = $(".password").val();
alert(username);
});
```